# do parallel in R issue

Tags: r, parallel-processing

I am trying to modify a large matrix containing 0,1,2 values and replacing the 2 by 1.
The matrix contains 500.000 columns and 7000 rows. The data is already read in by 50 rows and now I want to break it up in blocks and multi-thread using foreach() %dopar%.

```
> SNPchunk
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] 
[1,]    0    0    0    0    1    0    0    2    
[2,]    1    0    1    0    1    1    1    0    
[3,]    1    0    1    0    1    1    0    1   
[4,]    0    0    0    0    1    0    0    2    
[5,]    0    0    0    0    2    0    2    1    
[6,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    1   
[7,]    0    0    0    0    1    0    0    2  
[8,]    0    0    0    0    2    0    1    1   
[9,]    1    1    1    0    1    1    0    1   
[10,]   0    0    0    0    1    0    1    1
```

---

```
chunk = foreach (part = 1:snpsplit) %do% 
{
    snpchunk = SNPcomponents[,snp.start[part]:snp.stop[part]]

    #print(part)

    res = foreach(SNP=1:ncol(snpchunk), .combine='cbind') %dopar% 
    {
        a = snpchunk[,SNP]
        a[a==2] <- 1
        print(a)
    }           
}
```

with the print(a) statement the returned variable ***res*** is a matrix of n by x with all 2s replaced by 1s.

```
       result.1 result.2 result.3 result.4 result.5 result.6 result.7 result.8
[1,]        0        1        1        1        0        1        1        1
[2,]        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0
[3,]        1        0        0        0        0        0        0        0
[4,]        0        0        0        0        0        0        1        1
[5,]        0        1        1        1        0        0        1        1
[6,]        1        0        1        1        0        1        1        1
[7,]        0        1        1        1        0        0        1        1
[8,]        0        1        0        0        1        1        1        1
[9,]        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0
[10,]       1        1        0        0        0        0        0        1
```

However without the print(a) statement the returned variable ***res*** is a matrix of 1 by x containing only the value 1.

```
>res
result.1 result.2 result.3 result.4 result.5 result.6 result.7 result.8
   1        1        1        1        1        1        1        1
```

How do I get the first result without using the print statement?

Thank you for helping!
J.

Answer (score 0):

If you completely remove `print(a)` the `a[a==2] <- 1` line returns 1. That is why you should use `a` instead of `print(a)`

```
res = foreach(SNP=1:ncol(snpchunk), .combine='cbind') %dopar% 
{
    a = snpchunk[,SNP]
    a[a==2] <- 1
    a
}
```